# Getting parameter name and value from delegate

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, func

I have implemented a generic method for calling function in my web service methods and catching exceptions. The idea is to centralize the exception handling and log why the exception occured:

```
public class WebServiceHandler
{
     public T Execute<T>(Func<T> body)
            {
                //wrap everything in common try/catch
                try
                {                
                    return body();
                }
                catch (SoapException)
                {
                    //rethrow any pre-generated SOAP faults
                    throw;
                }           
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Logger.AddTextToLog(Logger.LogLevel.Error, "An error occured");
                    var innerExceptionMessage = ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : "";
                    throw GenerateSoapException(
                                                ex.Message,
                                                innerExceptionMessage, 
                                                SoapException.ServerFaultCode);
                }
            }
}
```

I'm using the method like this in my web service methods:

```
[WebMethod]
GetXXX(string param1, string param2)
{
var request = new GetXXXRequest(param1, param2);
     return _webServiceHandler.Execute(() => _controller.GetXXX(request));
}

[WebMethod]
GetYYY(string param1)
{
var request = new GetYYYRequest(param1);
     return _webServiceHandler.Execute(() => _controller.GetYYY(request));
}
```

In case of exceptions I would like to log the parameter names and values used as input to the controller.GetXXX(request) and controller.GetYYY(request) methods in the Execute method.

How can I achieve this? 
Or is there a better way to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 2):

I did not tried with expressions but I have a solution for delegates;

```
public static List<object> GetMethodParameterValues(Delegate method)
{
    var target = method.Target;
    if (target == null) return null;
    var fields = target.GetType().GetFields();
    var valueList = fields.Select(field => field.GetValue(target)).ToList();
    return valueList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't query the runtime for the that information magically, implicitly.

It is true that you can implicitly learn the complete identity of the currently executing method, its caller, its caller's caller and all of the stacktrace (except for the particular generic arguments in case of generic methods) by instantiating the `StackTrace` class or by calling the `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` method.

It is also true that the resulting `MethodBase` instances hold information about the methods' parameters and so, you might be able to learn the names of the parameters, but that's where it all ends. If a mechanism allowing you to implicitly probe for parameter or local variable values would've been invented then **everything** would be **a lot slower**.

What you **can** do, is help yourself, a bit, by means of the `Expression<Lambda>` class and its entourage. It's gonna be a bit slow, but you get to choose whether you want reviewable and easy to manage code, or misteriously hard to manage and very very fast code.

`Expression<Lambda>` is how LINQ manages to **not** do a full table scan of database tables but rather *understand* what you did with your query and translate that (at runtime) into SQL or whatever other language you might imagine (depending on the actual LINQ provider).

First of all, I would suggest splitting concerns into 2 categories:

1. Retrieving names and values (as implicitly as possible)
2. Using names and values (wherever you want to)

To make that happen you need to think about an entity which can hold the results of point 1. In my suggestion to you that would be a kind of `Dictionary<string, object>` but you can do whatever suits you best.

My suggestion can be used like so:

```
public void SomeMethod(string x, int y) {

    IDictionary<string, object> paramValues = Helper.TapInto(
        () => x, 
        () => y
    );

    // paramValues["x"] an paramValues["y"] will hold the values of x and y

}
```

So, on to the coding bit. You could write a `Helper` class like so:

```
public static class Helper {
}
```

In that `Helper` class you could invent a static method ( I called mine `TapInto` maybe that's not the best name for it ) which receives a primitive array of `Expression<Func<object>>` instances. It does that with a `params` modifier so that you can easily pass implicit lambdas to it. As a return it gives you a hashtable from `string` to `object` representing the "decompiled" variable names and their associated values.

In my case, I also created a private overload of that same method which is actually an "extension" method, to make the code clearer.

```
public static class Helper {

    // ... an overload of the TapInto method is about to appear right here

    public static IDictionary<string, object> TapInto(params Expression<Func<object>>[] parameterTouchers) {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (var toucher in parameterTouchers) {
            string name;
            object value;
            toucher.TapInto(out name, out value);
            result[name] = value;
        }

        return result;

    }
```

So all the public method does is iterate through the list and accumulate the yielded results into the dictionary.

Next let's look at the real magic, which happens in the `toucher.TapInto(out name, out value)` call:

```
public static class Helper {

    private static void TapInto(this Expression<Func<object>> @this, out string name, out object value) {

        Expression expression = @this.Body;
        if (expression is UnaryExpression)
            expression = (expression as UnaryExpression).Operand;

        name = (expression as MemberExpression).Member.Name;

        Func<object> compiledLambda = @this.Compile();
        value = compiledLambda();

    }

    // ... public helper method right here
}
```

What we're doing here is "we're looking inside" the lambda with a magnifying glass.
Because we're gonna use stuff other than `object` variables it's imminent to observe an implicit conversion like

```
.. int someParameter ..
object obj = someParameter;
```

which is only implicit in the actual C# code, but is actually compiled as an explicit conversion:

```
object obj = (object)someParameter;
```

But you might have a plain `object` parameter, like `object anotherParam`, in which case there would be no conversion at all.

That is why, upon observing the expression's intricate details, I presume I might find a conversion ( represented by the `UnaryExpression` class ) or not.

Actually it's like saying: In this particular case, my contract to the calling code is that it *may* send me only stuff which falls into these 2 categories:

1. Immediate `object` variable reference: `() => someObjectVariable`
2. Variable reference with a conversion: `() => (object)x`

The contract also accidentally states that the "conversion" bit can be replaced by a `UnaryExpression`, for instance: `() => !someBool`.

It also states that you cannot do something like:

- `() => 123`
- or `() => a + b + c + 100`
- or anything else in those directions

So, to wrap it up:

1. You could write your nice little helper
2. You could use it wherever you want to use it to produce maps between param names and their values although it's not 100% implicit, **but** at least it won't compile if you rename a parameter without complete refactoring or it will let you rename the parameter references if you choose to rename the parameters using refactoring
    (it also works on fields, local variables, etc)
3. Pass your dictionaries in between parts of your code that are interested in them and use them accordingly !

Answer (score 0):

You can use another parameter to the Execute method to get callback from function.
An Action or your result type. In this case string for example:

```
public T Execute<T>(Func<T> body, Action<string> callback)
            {
                //wrap everything in common try/catch
                try
                {  
                     //do stuff              
                    callback("results are...");
                }
```

You can also use a delegate:

```
public void CallbackDelegate( string str ); 


 public T Execute<T>(Func<T> body, CallbackDelegate callback)
            {
                //wrap everything in common try/catch
                try
                {  
                     //do stuff              
                    callback("results are...");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
sealed class Param
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Param(string name, object value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public T Execute<T>(Func<T> body, params Param[] parameters)
{
    //wrap everything in common try/catch
    try
    {
        return body();
    }
    catch (SoapException)
    {
        //rethrow any pre-generated SOAP faults
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Logger.AddTextToLog(Logger.LogLevel.Error, "An error occured");

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            Logger.AddTextToLog(
                                Logger.LogLevel.Error,
                                string.Format(
                                              "{0} : {1}",
                                              parameter.Name,
                                              parameter.Value ?? "null"));
        }

        var innerExceptionMessage = ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : "";
        throw GenerateSoapException(
                                    ex.Message,
                                    innerExceptionMessage,
                                    SoapException.ServerFaultCode);
    }
}
```

And then you call:

```
[WebMethod]
GetXXX(string param1, string param2)
{
    var request = new GetXXXRequest(param1, param2);
    return _webServiceHandler.Execute(() => _controller.GetXXX(request)
                                      new Parameter("param1", param1),
                                      new Parameter("param2", param2));
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is a way to do it. I was hoping to achieve my goal without handling the parameters explicitly, but time is a parameter here as well:)

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to add the request class as parameter to the Execute method like this:

```
public T Execute<T, TU>(Func<T> body, TU parameterClass) where TU : class
{
 //wrap everything in common try/catch
        try
        {                
            return body();
        }
        catch (SoapException)
        {
            //rethrow any pre-generated SOAP faults
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var serializedObject = ParameterUtil.GetPropertyNamesAndValues(parameterClass);                
            Logger.AddTextToLog(Logger.LogLevel.Error, string.Format("An error occured when calling braArkiv Web Services. Web service method arguments: {0}", serializedObject), ex);
            var innerExceptionMessage = ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : "";
            throw GenerateSoapException(
                                        ex.Message,
                                        innerExceptionMessage,
                                        SoapException.ServerFaultCode);
        }
}


 public static class ParameterUtil
    {       
        public static string GetPropertyNamesAndValues<T>(T o) where T : class
        {
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, o);
                stringWriter.Close();
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }            
        }        
    }
```

Usage:

```
[WebMethod]
GetXXX(string param1, string param2)
{
var request = new GetXXXRequest(param1, param2);
     return _webServiceHandler.Execute(() => _controller.GetXXX(request), request);
}
```

When an exception occurs I just serialize the parameterClass parameter containing the web service method parameters and add the string to my log.

Thank you all for the constructive input to my question!